# How to implement multiple plugins to a class in typescript

Tags: typescript

i have a relatively basic question:

What is the best practice, when you need to implement a way to extend a class with multiple plugins?

For example, when you have a database provider class, which has a "delete" method.

sometimes, you need to have the ability to soft delete items. So you may have a SoftDelete plugin for that database provider.

But then, you will also have a logging plugin, cause you want to log everytime an item was deleted or soft deleted... so you will have a Log plugin

how to implement this "pattern"?

Comment: please provide an example of what you currently have or what you have tried, otherwise your question might be closed.

Comment: What you are looking for sounds like [dependency injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection/140655#140655).